# Passing base class to function instead derived one

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a problem with the inheritance, here's my example code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Drawable {
    friend void draw( const Drawable &drawable );

    private:
        virtual void print() const = 0;
};

void draw( const Drawable &drawable ) {
    drawable.print();
}

class Rectangle : public Drawable {
    virtual void print() const override {
        std::cout << "Drawing rectangle...\n";
    }
};

class Square : public Rectangle {
    virtual void print() const override {
        draw( dynamic_cast< const Rectangle & >( *this ) );
        std::cout << "Drawing square...\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Square square;
    draw( square );

    return 0;
}
```

and more specifically with this function:

```cpp
struct Square : public Rectangle {
    virtual void print() const override {
        draw( dynamic_cast< const Rectangle & >( *this ) );
        std::cout << "Drawing square...\n";
    }
};
```

Is there any possibility to call the draw function from the Square class by casting this class to the Rectangle type?

The above example and the example with pointers causes stackoverflow because the print function from the Square class is running infinitely.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, you can call the draw function of Square class of a Square class object by casting to Rectangle class. No, you cannot call the draw function of Square class from the draw function of the Square class without a terminating case, since that results in infinite recursion.

Comment: You can however make a copy of the `Rectangle` slice of a `Square` and pass that as a temporary to `draw` like this: `draw(Rectangle(*this));`

Comment: Why are you hiding `print()` from the derived classes? Make it `protected`. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/nP4Kjn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it is your intent but you can explicitly invoke the
`Rectangle` specific version of `print()` from `Square`.

```
// draw( dynamic_cast< const Rectangle & >( *this ) );
Rectangle::print();
std::cout << "Drawing square...\n";
```

Using the `draw()` function will always select the more specific
version of `print()` (due to `virtual`).

---

Edit, now that the question has changed: you have to declare the
`print()` member function `protected` all the way down the hierarchy.

Comment: and in a situation where the print function would be private, is there any other way to call this function?

Comment: @Majrusz If it's private, then `draw()` must be made a `friend`. You should probably make it `protected` to let derived classes call it. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/nP4Kjn)

Comment: @Majrusz if the `print()` member function is private, the `draw()` function will not be able to call it.